# Elasticsearch [indices:admin/create]

Tags: python, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl

I am struggling with the Elasticsearch problem. I have set up ES Indices and using django_elasticsearch_dsl. I have tried to write tests for my application.

```
class SearchTestMixin(object):

    def setup_method(self):
        for index in registry.get_indices():
            if index.exists():
                index.delete()
            index.create()

    def teardown_method(self):
        for index in registry.get_indices():
            index.delete()
```

And I am getting error:

```
elasticsearch.exceptions.RequestError: RequestError(400, 'illegal_argument_exception', '[x][x.x.x.x:9300][indices:admin/create]')
```

How can I solved it and change indices permission settings?

Comment: Did you ever manage to fix this (without resorting to `*`)?